# How to modify a nested module of yaml file using bash script

Tags: linux, sed, yaml, jq, yq

I am trying to change one specific word in yaml file using sed command

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: abc12
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu:latest
    name: Ubuntu
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  - image: ngnix: latest
    name: Nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
...
```

Tried using the following command
`sed '/^ * image: ngnix:latest/,/^*[^:]*:s/imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent/imagePullPolicy: {}/' file.yaml`

I am required to change the imagePullPolicy content only for ngnix using sed/awk command.

Following is my desired output:

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: abc12
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu:latest
    name: Ubuntu
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  - image: ngnix: latest
    name: Nginx
    imagePullPolicy: {}
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Unless the use of `sed` is required, I suggest using a specific YAML parsing library.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: A <opinionated>good</opinionated> library for this use case would probably be https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Comment: Or better, the wrapper in Python over `jq` : `yq` https://github.com/kislyuk/yq

Answer (score 0):

one case (GNU sed)

```
sed -E '
/^\s*-\s*image:\s*ngnix/{
  :top
  N
  /imagePullPolicy/!btop
  s/(imagePullPolicy:).*/\1 \{\}/
}' file.yaml
```

However, this may not be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    match($0,/^[[:space:]-]*/) {
        if      ( RLENGTH > prevRlength ) { indent++ }
        else if ( RLENGTH < prevRlength ) { indent-- }
        prevRlength = RLENGTH

        key = val = substr($0,RLENGTH+1)
        sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",key)
        sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)

        indent2key[indent] = key
    }

    (indent == 2) && (indent2key[0] == "spec") && (indent2key[1] == "containers") {
        if ( $1 == "-" ) {
            gotImage = 0
        }

        if ( (key == "image") && (val ~ /^ngnix:/) ) {
            gotImage = 1
        }

        if ( gotImage && (key == "imagePullPolicy") && (val == "IfNotPresent") ) {
            sub(/:.*/,": {}")
        }
    }

    { print }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: abc12
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu:latest
    name: Ubuntu
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  - image: ngnix: latest
    name: Nginx
    imagePullPolicy: {}
```

The above assumes that `image:` always comes before `imagePullPolicy:` as in  the example you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;/- image: ngnix: latest/,/- image:/{n;s/(imagePullPolicy: ).*/\1{}/;ba}' input_file
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: abc12
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu:latest
    name: Ubuntu
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  - image: ngnix: latest
    name: Nginx
    imagePullPolicy: {}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your `YAML` line 9: `image: ngnix: latest` => `image: nginx:latest` (2 errors).

##### Fixed input:

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: abc12
spec:
  containers:
    - image: ubuntu:latest
      name: Ubuntu
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    - image: nginx:latest
      name: Nginx
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

##### Code with a proper `YAML` parser, [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```
yq -y '
  (
    .spec.containers[] | 
     select(.image=="nginx:latest" and .imagePullPolicy=="IfNotPresent")
    .imagePullPolicy
   ) = {}
' file
```

Credits to emanuele6 from jq@libera.irc

##### [Online Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VVRa93_OSwZ)

##### Output

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: abc12
spec:
  containers:
    - image: ubuntu:latest
      name: Ubuntu
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    - image: nginx:latest
      name: Nginx
      imagePullPolicy: {}
```

**To edit `inplace`, you can use `-yi`**.

Answer (score 0):

Dead simple sed, assuming the only `IfNotPresent` string is the one you want to replace in the lines from `image: ngnix` to `imagePullPolicy`:

```
 sed '/image: ngnix:/,/imagePullPolicy/ s/IfNotPresent/{}/' file.yaml
```

In other words, find your specific range of lines, and then do the simplest possible replacement withing that `/START/,/END/` range